# jQuery events after the $.post is happening before the request finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, .post

I have the following code, and for some odd reason, the order in which the events are happening is not making sense to me. Is there anyway in which I can make it so that it goes in the order?

```
var vm_good = false;
console.log("Before", vm_good);
    $.post("./ajax/call_price", {id: product_id}, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
           $(".unit-price span").html(value);
        });
        vm_good = true;
        console.log("Inside", vm_good);
        enableNext();
    }, 'json');
    console.log("After", vm_good);
```

And the results on the console window is:

```
>Before false
>After false
>Inside true
>window.vm_good // I called it manually after the page loaded
>>true
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**!  This behavior is by design.

Comment: The post request is asynchronous. It does not block. The interpreter moves on and continues processing, then handles that once the server has responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.post` is a shorthand of `$.ajax`. `A` in AJAX stands for asynchronous, so interpreter will execute next command, while `$.post` will run your event handler (`function(data)`) when your request is done. If your request wouldn't be asynchronous then your browser would freeze, because it would wait for your request to finish.

You can use `$.when(deffered).then(handler)` to execute code after your request is done:

```
var callPrice = $.post("./ajax/call_price", {id: product_id}, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
       $(".unit-price span").html(value);
    });
    vm_good = true;
    console.log("Inside", vm_good);
    enableNext();
}, 'json');

$.when(callPrice).then(function () {
    console.log("After", vm_good);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the helpful information as well =)

Answer (score 2):

`.post()` is an asynchronous request. that means JS doesn't wait for it to finish, it just move on to next instruction.

You need to put  `console.log("After", vm_good);` inside your post callback like this-

```
var vm_good = false;
console.log("Before", vm_good);
    $.post("./ajax/call_price", {id: product_id}, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
           $(".unit-price span").html(value);
        });
        vm_good = true;
        console.log("Inside", vm_good);
        enableNext();

        console.log("After", vm_good); // you should put this here
    }, 'json');
```